# ELO rating for simple hot-or-not sorting?

Tags: php, sorting

I'm looking to have the user sort through a list of ~30 items using a hot-or-not system. The list is a small defined number and only needs to be sorted by the single user. I could have the user drag-drop a sorted list, but a hot-or-not system would be better.

From a bit of research it looks like ELO rating would be the fastest option.

How do I use this PHP class? https://github.com/Chovanec/elo-rating

Answer (score 0):

i would write my own its very simple.

```
//first i calculate the win probability.
$a_win_prob = 1/(1+pow(10,($b_elo - $a_elo)/400));
$b_win_prob = 1/(1+pow(10,($a_elo - $b_elo)/400));

//than i make a K value for a and b
if($a_elo < 2100){
    $a_k = 20;  
}elseif($a_elo > 2300){
    $a_k = 10;
}else{
    $a_k = 15;  
}

if($b_elo < 2100){
    $b_k = 20;  
}elseif($b_elo > 2300){
    $b_k = 10;
}else{
    $b_k = 15;  
}

//than i calculate both elo values.
if($win_side === "a"){
    $a_elo_new = $a_elo + $a_k*(2*$a_win_prob);
    $b_elo_new = $b_elo - $b_k*(2*$b_win_prob);
}else{
    $a_elo_new = $a_elo - $a_k*(2*$a_win_prob);
    $b_elo_new = $b_elo + $b_k*(2*$b_win_prob);
}
//than i can put them in a database
```

this i the basic set up for a elo rating systum
its much simpler than the class.
you could even rewrite this to be a function.

i hope this will help